Am i supposed to continue with fasting after spotting a drop of blood caused by contraceptive medicines?its not heidh its happened several days
Is it permissable continue with sawm and salat after spotting a drop of blood caused by contraceptive medicine.its not a menstruation its happens several days.And after a drop its doesn't continue.i may take ghasl and pray but fasting im so confused about it.

If you are certain that it is not menstrual blood then obviously you can fast. We really can't tell you what it is based on the given description. Questions asking for personal advice are off-topic.

@UmH I think this question can be re-phrased, actually I had the same question in mind because in my family a woman had bleeding just because of medical examination.
